# Disable the "bid" button from WooCommerce product pages for the author

Tags: php, wordpress, button, woocommerce, product

I would like to Removal/disable/hide of "bid" button from product pages in WooCommerce for post authors of the post.

I am using WC vendors pro + Woocommerce + Wp Geine Auctions + WC Vendors Auction.

Please find the link of the screen shot below:

[image]

The Live [**Link to the product**](https://www.allaboutphilately.com/product/test-41/)

How can I do it please?

Comment: screen shot added. http://i.imgur.com/RtMaWRX.png

Comment: Hello,I tried it today, couldnt try this before as my website was broken. The code works well but if the product is uploaded via excel the code works but if the product uploaded via admin panel and the admin assigns the product to the vendor then vendor is able to bid however the message appears not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this buttons are already customized by you or some plugins, I am not sure at 100% that it will work for you, even if it works on my test server.

The first function is a conditional function that detects for a product if the current user is the author (the vendor) of this product.

Then on shop and archives pages the add to cart button is replace by a custom button liked to the product.

To finish on single product page the button is replace by a fake button with a custom text *(here "Not Allowed")*…

Here is the code:

```
// Custom conditional function (detecting the vendor of a product)
if( ! function_exists( 'is_the_vendor' ) ){
    function is_the_vendor( $product ){

        $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();

        $product_id = method_exists( $product, 'get_id' ) ? $product->get_id() : $product->id;

        // Get the product post object to get the post author
        $post_obj = get_post( $product_id );
        $post_author = $post_obj->post_author;

        if( $post_author == $current_user_id ) return true;
        else return false;
    }
}

// Shop and archives pages: we replace the button add to cart by a link to the product
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'custom_text_replace_button', 10, 2 );
function custom_text_replace_button( $button, $product  ) {

    if( is_the_vendor( $product ) ){
        $button_text = __("View product", "woocommerce");
        return '<a class="button" href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">' . $button_text . '</a>';
    } else {
        return $button;
    }
}
// replacing add to cart button and quantities by a custom inactive button
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'replacing_template_single_add_to_cart', 1, 0 );
function replacing_template_single_add_to_cart() {
    global $product;

    if( is_the_vendor( $product ) ):

        // Removing add to cart button and quantities
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );

        // The text replacement
        add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', function(){

            // set below your custom text
            $text = __('Not allowed', 'woocommerce');

            // Temporary style CSS
            $style_css = 'style="border: solid 1px red; padding: 0 6px; text-align: center;"';

            // Output your custom text
            echo '<a class="button custom-button" style="background-color: grey !important;">'.$text.'</a>';
        }, 30 );

    endif;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works. you will get this:

[image]

And this:

[image]